# assistance with looping code in java

Tags: java, loops, boolean, variable-assignment

I need help with looping my code in Java. So far I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class chara{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int count = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Input a string");
        String user=input.nextLine();
        if(user.length()<7)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
        }
        System.out.println("Now input a letter to be replaced");
        String letter = input.next();
        if(letter.length()!=1) 
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
        }
        String user2 = user.replace(letter, "-");
        String user3 = user.replace(letter, "");
        count += (user.length() - user3.length());
        System.out.println(user2);
        System.out.println(user3);
        System.out.println("#"+letter+"'s: "+count);
    }
}
```

The code does everything I want it to except that when the string condition is not met (user<7, letter!=1) the program terminates and what I need it to do is ask the question again. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Check my answer on your previous thread on this topic!!

Comment: Please do us the courtesy of formatting your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your looping code in method that can be called, then when the conidtion is not met you can go back to your question, and depending on that condidtion, quit the program, or call the loop method.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a loop with a break condition, this should do it for you:

```
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
       System.out.println("Input a string");
       String user=input.nextLine();
       while (true)
       {
           if(user.length() <7 ) {break;}
           input = new Scanner(System.in); 
           System.out.println("Too long, input a string < 7");
             user=input.nextLine();

       }

   if(user.length()<7)......
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to wrap your main logic within a loop with a boolean condition.  This condition stays true when there is an "error" in the input.  The condition is then false when the user proceeds as wanted.

Your code would look as so :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tester{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int count = 0;
        boolean keepGoing = true;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        while(keepGoing) {

            System.out.println("Input a string");
            String user=input.nextLine();
           if(user.length()<7)
           {
               keepGoing = true;
               //enter an error message here
           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println("Now input a letter to be replaced");
                String letter = input.next();
                if(letter.length()!=1) 
                {
                    keepGoing = true;
                    //enter an error message here
                }
                else
                {
                    String user2 = user.replace(letter, "-");
                    String user3 = user.replace(letter, "");
                    count += (user.length() - user3.length());
                    System.out.println(user2);
                    System.out.println(user3);
                    System.out.println("#"+letter+"'s: "+count);
                    keepGoing = false;
                }
           }
        }   
        input.close();  //Close resources
    }
}
```

### Unrelated

The convention is that class names start with a capital letter. In your case your class should be `Chara`, not `chara`.

Also, when opening resources make sure you close them.  This is to avoid having resources leaked.  Some IDEs will tell you something like this `Resource leak: 'input' is never closed`.  It's a good idea to use a good IDE to help you with potential problems like this one.